# Can the "user" RSS feed include comments that respond to that user?

Tags: feature-request, rss

It would be useful, I think, if comments that are directed *to* me could turn up in the RSS feed that is associated with my user page, because then my RSS reader would notify me that there is a comment on SE. Comments *by* me are there already.

Alternatively, is there already a way to be notified by SE of incoming comments (other than by e-mail every three hours or daily, which I don't want to do)?

Comment: Peter, does http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64928/2509 meet your needs? If not this should probably be moved to meta.stackoverflow.com as it is a network wide issue.

Comment: Actually, [it appears that several variations have already been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62588/2509) over there (see the bullet point on adding comments to the feeds).